# How do I get rid of the elif Syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Image of Code Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwGOJ.png)

```
while Time5 == "true":
        Act5 = input("\nWhat would you like to do this year? You can: Play Videogames | Punch your parents | Browse the internet | Youtube | Steal Food |Check Stats | Check Assests: \n")
        if Act5 == "Check Stats":
            print("Your Stats")
            print("Sanity:{}".format(Sanity))
            print("Happiness:{}".format(Happiness))
            print("Health{}".format(Health))  
            print("Money{}".format((Money))       
        elif Act5 == "Steal Food": 
            print("You went over to your local Wendys and stole a Happy Meal.")
            Happiness = Happiness + 12
            print("The addreniline RUSH gave you 12 extra happiness\n")
            if Happiness > 100:
                print("Your HAPPINESS is maxed.")
            Wendy = input("You see another door to your left. It is the staff door. Will you enter? Yes or No \n")
```

I'm trying to make a life simulator.
I keep getting an invalid syntax warning on this section.
There seems to be no indenting errors.
It used to work.
Its only this section that doesn't work
If you want to see more code, go to this website:  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HR5ahjM4B6wKOSEpeVRxXGrF9wCNTAp-OizdRl2zKuA/edit?usp=sharing and scroll down to version 4.

Comment: check parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the line

`print("Money{}".format((Money))`

is causing you problems, because like gilch said in the comment above, you have one too many parentheses. Modify that line to

`print("Money{}".format(Money))`

and see if that works!